# Multiple Databases & Backup Migrate Module

Tags: 7, backups

Without going into the details, our Drupal site actually has 2 databases that must always be in sync. That means if one is backed up, the other one needs to be backed up at the same time and that they would both need to be restored at the same time. (For the curious, one is Drupal and the other is for our CRM.)

I am using Node Squirrel to host off-site backups through the [backup and migrate](https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) module so that if something happens to the server image, I'll at least have those.

When I look at my off-site back ups, I only see one .mysql file per day but I am backing up two databases.

How can I check and see if the .mysql file contains a backup of both databases and if it's only one database, how do I tell which one and make sure they are both backed up together?

Thanks!

Edit: My production server was corrupted and I needed to restore the last backup, but apparently it was only one and not both databases that were being backed up. Furthermore, my test and dev sites were also being backed up to the same location because I imported the Drupal database, which included my backup and migrate settings, to those locations so none of the back ups were dependable. I need to figure out the best practice for using this module: making sure test and dev sites aren't backing up to it and that it's backing up all my databases, not just one.

Comment: What are you using a webhost that provides dev and test environments? Like are you on [Pantheon](https://pantheon.io/)? [Acquia](https://www.acquia.com/)? or locally on your computer? or ...

Comment: I set up the environments manually. 2 are on 2 separate VPS running Debian and one is locally on a Mac